# How to share data between threads using QThread

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to learn how to share data between threads using `QThread`.

In my code below
when I try to print the value of `worker_str` sometimes i get an exception in the file `qdebug.cpp`:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**p** was 0x111011101110111.
```

and sometimes it prints `worker_str` as `""`.

What I'm doing wrong? also, I should call `thread->quit();` whenever I don't need that thread running anymore?

---

```
#include "worker.h"

App::App(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);


    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    Worker* worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QString str = "hello world";

    connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, [worker, str]
    {
        worker->test(str);
    });

    connect(worker, &Worker::finished, thread, [worker, thread]
    {
        qDebug() << "worker_str: " <<  worker->worker_str;

        thread->quit();
    });    

    connect( worker, &Worker::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
    connect( thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    thread->start();
}
```

---

```
//worker.h
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker() {};
    ~Worker() {};

    QString worker_str;

public slots:
    void test(QString str)
    {
        worker_str = str;
        qDebug() << "WORKER: str: " << str;
        emit finished();
    };

signals:
    void finished();

};
```

Comment: If you declare `Worker::test` as a slot, use it like a slot.

Comment: @Atmo i get the same errors when its not declared as a slot.

Comment: The comment was meant the way that you should use Qt's signals and slots to share data between threads. Or the classic apporach - use mutexes.

Comment: @chehrlic could you give an example?

Comment: It is only a slot if you use as a parameter in `QObject::connect`; if you call a slot yourself, for instance in a lambda (and even if the lambda itself is a parameter itself inside `connect`), you are definitely using it as a normal method. As @chehrlic has correctly understood, I meant for you to (check in the doc and) write `connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::test)`.

Comment: Before you ask, I know the signal and slots are not compatible, I have not thought about the best solution to pass your string as a parameter of some signal (if I had, I would be writing an answer, not just a comment) but it is a little bit hard to do with on a code sample that is clearly written as only an exercise for you to understand signals and slots. You could try with a separate class to send a signal with the string right after you start the thread maybe...

Answer (score 0):

About the code: I think the object "QString str" is no longer in memory after leaving the constructor scope. Make the variable a member of the class App.

Generally look into the topics mutex, lock guard or qt signal/slots. What you use in the end is up to your requirements.

Comment: I see ty, is it 'safe' to have a worker thread running like this: https://pastebin.com/K6wPjwFY